# How to stop vuejs method variable from updating data variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a strange js/vuejs problem that when a variable is updated inside a function (getting data from data(){}), it goes up the data also updates it.

Here is a code example. It checks if user has no profile image, it will send the image name to an api via axios, if user has already images then it will append the current image to the list and send it to the api:

```
addImage (file) {
    var URL = 'http://foo.com/api'; 

    var images = this.person.images;

    let att = []
    if(images.length) {
        att = images
        att.push(file.name)
    }else{
        att.push(file.name)
    }

    axios.post(URL, {
        attachements: att
    }).then(

        // update dom

    ).catch(err => {})
},
```

The problem here is that `this.person.images` gets updated, even though I just want to use it to get the current list of images.

If you check the if/else block when `att.push(file.name)` is executed the `this.person.images;` also gets updated. I am using the `att` only to store the current list of images and send it to api.

Is there anyway to use `this.person.image` to get the information only?

I could use `const att = this.person.image` but then I would not be able to update `att` afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More simple solution would be

```
var images=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.person.images))
```

avoid looping.

Answer (score 1):

Because in Javascript when you do :

```
 var images = this.person.images;
```

The value of images is now a reference for "this.person.images".

One idea to solve that problem is to loop through each item of "Images" Array and add it to the "att" array like so :

```
addImage (file) {
    var URL = 'http://foo.com/api'; 

    var images = this.person.images;

    let att = []
    if(images.length) {

   for (var i = 0,len = images.length; i < len; i++) {
        att.push(images[i]);
    }
        att.push(file.name)
    }else{
        att.push(file.name)
    }

    axios.post(URL, {
        attachements: att
    }).then(

        // update dom

    ).catch(err => {})
},
```

Basically replace `att = images` with :

```
   for (var i = 0,len = images.length; i < len; i++) {
            att.push(images[i]);
        }
```

Comment: I am surprised this is the only solution for it. I had thought of doing the same but I assumed there might be a better way. Is there?

Comment: Have a look at this array function in Javascript, it could be the solution for your problem.
 https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_copywithin.asp

Comment: var images=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.person.images)) . use this for simple solution